# Multiplying along an arbitrary axis?

Tags: python, tensorflow

If I have the output of a layer with shape `[batch_size, height, width, depth]` and another tensor of shape `[depth]`, how can I multiply the first tensor by the second such that each slice along the `depth` direction is multiplied by the corresponding value in the second tensor. That is, if the second tensor is `[4, 5, 6]`, then the multiplication is:

```
tensor1[:, :, :, 0] * 4
tensor1[:, :, :, 1] * 5
tensor1[:, :, :, 2] * 6
```

Also, is there a name for this kind of multiplication that I didn't know to search for? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is straightforward. Just multiply both tensors. For example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tensor = tf.Variable(tf.ones([2, 2, 2, 3]))
depth = tf.constant([4, 5, 6], dtype=tf.float32)
result = tensor * depth

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
print(sess.run(result))
```

Comment: Just to make sure the correct axis is used for multiplications you could reshape `depth` to `[1, 1, 1, 3]`. (You can also use `tf.expand_dims()`)

Comment: Yes, I agree. Broadcasting is implicit in my example, so maybe something like `depth = tf.reshape(tf.constant([4, 5, 6], dtype=tf.float32), shape=[1, 1, 1, 3])` would be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with the following:

```
a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = [5, 2])
b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = 2)

c = tf.concat(1, [tf.mul(x, y) for x, y in zip(tf.split(0, 2, b), tf.split(1, 2, a))])

sess = tf.Session()
print sess.run(c, feed_dict = {a: np.ones([5, 2]), b: [5, 6]})
```

Looks a little bit odd, but it seems to work fine for me. I've used 2d tensor, but you definetely could extend this to your case.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question, "is there a name for this kind of multiplication that I didn't know to search for?", it is an element-wise multiplication with broadcasting. Broadcasting refers to operations that implicitly replicate elements of a tensor to make it compatible with a second tensor used in the element-wise operation. Many Tensorflow operations use the same broadcasting methods used by Numpy, which are further described [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html)